# in in my application i use sdk 25.0.0 but when i run it requires 26.0.2 that doesn't exist sdk and wants to download it,

Tags: java, android

i spent all day to solve this issue. and i,m getting this  ..... please share your experience with me. Thanks

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   process D:\AppData\sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments
>   {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   D:\AppData\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar -M
>   \?\D:\Android_projects\OnSale_worked_01.02.2018\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S D:\Android_projects\OnSale_worked_01.02.2018\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug
>   -m -J \?\D:\Android_projects\OnSale_worked_01.02.2018\app\build\generated\source\r\debug
>   -F D:\Android_projects\OnSale_worked_01.02.2018\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_
>   --custom-package com.veyseloglu.OnSaleApp -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\D:\Android_projects\OnSale_worked_01.02.2018\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   --no-version-vectors}

Comment: This is not sufficient. Please include your build.gradle file.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25               and build version doesnt exist, android 3.0.1

Comment: @Mehemmed Mamedov I think you have used some dependency in your gradle file which supports sdk version 26 or higher .so check your gradle file

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-3.1.3.jar')

Comment: never used 26 or 26+ version

Comment: compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/woosimprinter_bt.jar')

Comment: for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0 and com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0 you have used version 25.4.0 and your compile sdk version is 25.0.0 so how it will support so update your dependency.what is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: But the easiest way is update your build.gradle file with sdk version 26

Comment: i did it, but could,t solve by this way.

Comment: provide build.gradle file data in your question so it will be easy to detect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From OP's comment, possible reason could be `mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar` which used sdk version `26` earlier (recently changed to `27`).

My suggestion would be instead of using the jar file try -

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
```

Nevertheless please include your gradle file in the question body instead of comments.